# How i can generate dynamic id for text field and get data from array of model in asp.net 4 mvc3

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, model

This is my first post here! :)

I have to return an array of my model from my controller class to the view page. I want to put the data into a text box and generate dynamic id's for each text box to use the data further via JavaScript (that's why I am looking for dynamic id's).

## Model

```
public partial class BhBuyerChart
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    public BhBuyerChart(string n, string d)
    {
        Date = n;
        Quantity = d;
    }
}
```

---

## Controller

```
public ActionResult test()
{
     BhBuyerChart[] model = new BhBuyerChart[7];

     DataTable dt = (DataTable)ExecuteDB(ERPTask.AG_GetAllShipmentRecord, CurrentUserId);
     List<BhBuyerChart> ItemList = null;
     ItemList = new List<BhBuyerChart>();
     int i = 0;
     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     {
         model[i] = new BhBuyerChart(dr["Shipmentdate"].ToString(), dr["ShipmentQuantity"].ToString());
         i++;
     };

     return View(model);
}
```

---

## View

### 1st Attempt

```
<div>
    <% for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {%>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Quantity, new { id = "Quantity"})%>    <%--value can assign from model but dnt know how to assing dynamic id --%>

    <input type="text" value="<%= i %>" id="text<%=i %>"/>                 <%--dynamic id can be assinged dnt knw how to assing model value here in textbox --%>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

### 2nd Attempt

```
<div>
<% int i = 0; %>
<% foreach (ERP.Domain.Model.BhBuyerChart user in Model) {  %>
      <% i++; %>
      <input type="text"; id="textbox<% i %>" ; value="<% user.Quantity %>" />   
 <% } %>
 </div>
```

---

I really appreciate everybody's attention and help and I look forward to your responses!

Comment: Are you wanting to get the quantity back during a POST?

Comment: yes i need to assign the quantity values in a array variable. i need that array variable to create graph. thats why with the textbox i need generate id for each to use them in javascript or smthng

Comment: take a look at my answer. This is the way to go for your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it for you. Effectively what you're going to do is build a new method inside the controller so that you can POST back to the controller with the updated values. Further, you don't want the `Quantity` fields to have different names because they won't bind - and so each one you build will say `Quantity` in the `name` **and** `id` attribute when the HTML is generated.

If I've misunderstood your need please comment.

## Controller

```
public ActionResult test()
{
     BhBuyerChart[] model = new BhBuyerChart[7];

     DataTable dt = (DataTable)ExecuteDB(ERPTask.AG_GetAllShipmentRecord, CurrentUserId);
     List<BhBuyerChart> ItemList = null;
     ItemList = new List<BhBuyerChart>();
     int i = 0;
     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     {
         model[i] = new BhBuyerChart(dr["Shipmentdate"].ToString(), dr["ShipmentQuantity"].ToString());
         i++;
     };

     return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test(ICollection<BhBuyerChart> charts)
{
    // This allows you to POST to the controller with the modified values

    // Note that based on what you're collecting client side the charts
    // will ONLY contain the Quantity value, but they will all have one.
    // If you need the date you can either show a text box for that or
    // even place the date inside a hidden field.
}
```

## View

```
<form method="post" action="/{controllername}/test">
...
<div>
    <% for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {%>
        <!-- This line will both bind the value and allow you to POST -->
        <!-- this form back to the controller with the new values -->

        <!-- NOTE: each control is actually going to be named the same -->
        <!-- but when it's posted will post in order to the collection -->
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Quantity) %>

        <!-- You may or may not want this here so that you can get the -->
        <!-- value of the date back to the server during a POST -->
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Date) %>
    <% } %>
</div>
...
</form>
```

## JavaScript

Now in JavaScript what you can do is use jQuery to simply get a listing of all the elements named `Quantity` like this and use them from that array.

```
// with this ([0].Quantity) being the template
// we'll use a simple wildcard selector to find
// all of them that end with Quantity.

var elems = $("[name$=Quantity]")

// now you have a list of the elements that you
// can use to populate the other array with -
// getting the value with a statement like...

var val = elems[0].val();
```

Comment: Thnx for your help. But do i have to post back to another method with updated data? the code for graph is in the same view page. sorry i should make it clear earlier. the array of model i am sending form controller to test.aspx and the code for my graph chart is in the same view. i just want to update the array variable of graph with model data

Comment: If the data you're trying to update is client-side then you don't need to POST back at all. Are you indicating that you just need to update some data on the client at runtime and then if the user refreshes the browser those changes don't persist?

Comment: @AnupamRoy, please don't post code to a comment. Edit your question and then add a comment letting me know I need to look at your edit. You should be able to delete the comment still.

Comment: i am using google chart api. here i have a array variable called data[[],[]] . the api script is on client site in the same viewpage where i am returning the model array. when i get the model from controller on client site i want to update data[[],[]] with model value. and the script will generate updated graph chart for me with new values on the same viewpage (client site) and i need to persist the updated data.

Comment: So you can use the jQuery I provided to get at the values that are brought back and place them into the array right? And when you say persist the updated data - what updated data are you speaking of specifically? Please update your question with a detailed explanation of what you're trying to do with the data you get back and then what data you expect to persist.

Comment: But this jQuery is not working. by $("#Quantity") its cant get the value. :(  if a model is not an array (m => m.Quantity) than this jQuery works but when the model is an array its simple doesnt work :(

Comment: it doesnt give me any error message. the 2nd like of jQuery is just doesnt execute i guess. when i tried alert(alems)  it gives me [object Object]  and when i tried alert(alems[0]) obviously it returned me undefined ... and when i tried alert(alems[0].val())   it just doesnt show me anythng... i guess that didnt execute at all.

Comment: thnx for your time. i have made this. simply this code generate dynamic id for me     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Quantity, new { id = i })%>         and i can use the data with this jQuery code                parseInt(document.getElementById(i).value)    :)

Comment: @AnupamRoy, I just wanted to let you know that you're not using jQuery and that explains why this wasn't working. Lookup jQuery in Google and you'll see what it is. Best of luck to you.

Comment: thnx @Mike . and sorry for the confusion and for ur time ... thnx again

Answer (score 0):

You need the excellent extension made by Steven Sanderson called `BeginCollectionItem`. For each row in your Model, each inputs will inherit an unique guid that you can reuse for validation or other stuff.

For more information on how to use the extension step by step, please go see the article on Steven Sanderson's blog : [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

The article was made for MVC2 but it work in MVC3 too. It should work in MVC4 but i haven't tested yet.

## View

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) {
    <% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("bhBuyerItem")) { %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity) %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date) %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

## The extension method

```
public static class HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions
{
    private const string idsToReuseKey = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_";

    public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
    {
        var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
        string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
        html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));

        return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex));
    }

    public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
    {
        return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
    }

    private static Queue<string> GetIdsToReuse(HttpContextBase httpContext, string collectionName)
    {
        // We need to use the same sequence of IDs following a server-side validation failure,  
        // otherwise the framework won't render the validation error messages next to each item.
        string key = idsToReuseKey + collectionName;
        var queue = (Queue<string>)httpContext.Items[key];
        if (queue == null) {
            httpContext.Items[key] = queue = new Queue<string>();
            var previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request[collectionName + ".index"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds))
                foreach (string previouslyUsedId in previouslyUsedIds.Split(','))
                    queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId);
        }
        return queue;
    }

    private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
        private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

        public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

            previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well after several tries i guess i have able to make this

```
<%for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)%>
<%  {  %>
  <div style="width:100%; float:left">
     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Date, new { id= i+500 })%>
     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Quantity, new { id = i })%>

     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Quantity) %>

   </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val = [[], []];
    for (k = 0; k <= 1; k++) {
        val[k][0] = document.getElementById(k+300).value;
        val[k][1] = parseInt(document.getElementById(k).value);

    }
</script>
```

this gonna take dynamic data from model array and create dynamic id for each textbox and assign them into variable using dynamic id